# JPA command to get an ID from foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

what is different from this syntax on JPA

```
q.setMerchant(em.find(Merchant.class, m.getId()));
```

between

```
q.getMerchant.setId(m.getId());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, the Merchant object becomes an attached entity and in the second case if it is not already attached it stays detached.

Comment: so in case 2, if i dont write these code : q.setmerchant(getMerchant()); , the id will return null. is it right?

Comment: if you dont set the Merchant object then the q.getMerchant() might return null and the q.getMerchant().setId(m.getId()) may throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example sets the merchant of q to the merchant found with the I'd m.getId() . Your second example retrieves the merchant returned from the call to q and then sets it's id to m.getId() . It does NOT set the merchant on q to the merchant identified my m.getId()

Comment: i see.. so we have to set q.setmerchant(getMerchant()) first before we set the id. thanks